# Android Floating Action Button works on API 23 emulator but not on API 17

Tags: java, android

i have put a floating action button on an activity with fragments and if i run this in the emulator (API 23) it works and i can click it with animations but if i run it on my phone (API 17) it doesn't work and if i click it it doesn't even register. Here is my code for the activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#067fca"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip

        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#0023b0"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />



</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabSqnMan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:background="#067fca"
    app:backgroundTint="#067fca"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="230dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:backgroundTint="#0023b0"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabDeleteIndividual"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:backgroundTint="#f44336"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabDeleteAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:backgroundTint="#e040fb"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"/>
```

and my code in the java class:

```
public class SquadronManagement extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
public FloatingActionButton fabSqnMan, fabAdd, fabDelete, fabDeleteAll;
public Boolean FabOpen = false;
public Animation fab_open, fab_close, rotate_forward, rotate_backward;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_squadron_management);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("Squadron Management");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    fabSqnMan = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabSqnMan);
    fabSqnMan.hide();
    fabAdd = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
    fabAdd.hide();
    fabDelete = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabDeleteIndividual);
    fabDelete.hide();
    fabDeleteAll = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabDeleteAll);
    fabDeleteAll.hide();
    fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
    fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
    rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_forward);
    rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_backward);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 3:
                    fabSqnMan.show();
                    break;
                default:
                    fabSqnMan.hide();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance() {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_squadron_management, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return new VerifyCadets();
            case 1:
                return new ViewRegister();
            case 2:
                return new ManageCadets();
            case 3:
                return new ManageSchedule();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Verify Cadets";
            case 1:
                return "View Register";
            case 2:
                return "Manage Cadets";
            case 3:
                return "Manage Schedule";

        }
        return null;
    }
}

public void FABAnimation(){

    if(FabOpen){

        fabSqnMan.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
        fabAdd.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fabDelete.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fabDeleteAll.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fabAdd.setClickable(false);
        fabDelete.setClickable(false);
        fabDeleteAll.setClickable(false);
        FabOpen = false;
    } else {

        fabSqnMan.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        fabAdd.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fabDelete.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fabDeleteAll.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fabAdd.setClickable(true);
        fabDelete.setClickable(true);
        fabDeleteAll.setClickable(true);
        FabOpen = true;
    }
}

public void onClick(View v){
    int id = v.getId();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.fabSqnMan:
            FABAnimation();
            break;
        case R.id.fabAdd:

            break;
        case R.id.fabDeleteIndividual:

            break;
        case R.id.fabDeleteAll:

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673522/floatingactionbutton-onclicklistener-not-working-on-api-17), there is enough description about your problem

Comment: Yeah i had a look at that earlier but i am not using a recylerview

Comment: Did you solved this problem? I'm facing something similar, emulator with API24, but when running on real device with API23 I get a runtime exception...